# Android - Will add too many classes inside a Fragment affect memory?

Tags: android, class, memory, android-fragments

I have a Fragment which will load all data by itself. So I created inside it an Asynctask extending class and a Comparator extending class to sort AsyncTask retrieved data. Here is the code:

```
public class FragmentWidgetDrawer extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //some code...
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //some code...


        return view;
    }

private final class WidgetsLoadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            //some code...
            return null;

        }
    }

public static class WidgetAndShortcutNameComparator implements Comparator<Object> {

        WidgetAndShortcutNameComparator(PackageManager pm) {
            //ctor
        }

        public final int compare(Object a, Object b) {
            //some code...
            return mCollator.compare(labelA, labelB);
        }
    };
```

So, would adding these classes increase the size of the memory needed by the fragment at the time when I instance it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they will take up memory, but not much (500 bytes per class - [source](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html)) and it's common practice to nest async tasks and onClickListeners inside activity or fragment.

Comment: so, should I create new file for that nested classes?

Comment: You should do whatever is more convenient for you as the performance gain is negligible.